# Polymorphic construction from String identifier

Tags: java, polymorphism, yaml

I'm trying to setup a polymorphic ExportRule system for my program, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to construct the desired ExportRule from a config file which has the ExportRule defined at the top of the file via a String.

I was looking to do something like this:

```
private ExportRule loadExportRule(String fileName) throws IOException, InvalidConfigurationException, FileNotFoundException{
    if(fileName == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("fileName cannot be null!");
    }
    YamlConfiguration exportRuleConfig = new YamlConfiguration();
    exportRuleConfig.load(getFilePath(fileName));

    return ExportRules.fromString(exportRuleConfig.getString("exportRule")).fromYamlConfiguration(exportRuleConfig);
}
```

where ExportRules is an enum mapping a String to the actual .class (which extends ExportRule) and then would call a static fromFileConfiguration() factory method to generate the ExportRule from the file which looks like this:

```
exportRule: nameOfExportRule
//all the configurationstuff for the rule
```

The problem I'm having is how to actually call the fromFileConfiguration() method as it is a static method and therefore java will not allow me to guarantee it's existence via the ExportRule interface

Is there a clean way to achieve something like this or do I have to do some kind of switch statement in my enum for each ExportRule?

edit:

Thank you glee8e!

here's my enum:

```
public enum ExportRules {
COMMENT_CONCAT("CommentConcat") {
    @Override
    public ExportRule fromFileConfiguration(FileConfiguration fileConfiguration) throws InvalidConfigurationException {
        return CommentConcat.fromFileConfiguration(fileConfiguration);
    }
};

private String name;

ExportRules(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public abstract ExportRule fromFileConfiguration(FileConfiguration fileConfiguration) throws InvalidConfigurationException;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public static ExportRules fromString(String str) {
    for(ExportRules rule : ExportRules.values()) {
        if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(rule.getName())) return rule;
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymorphism is not for static stuff but instance methods, at least in Java. Make your `fromFileConfiguration` an abstract instance method, and implememt it in individual constants:

```
public enum ExportRules {
    A_RULE {
         @Override public ExportRule fromFileConfiguration(YamlConfiguration c) {...}
    },
    //...
    public abstract ExportRule fromFileConfiguration(YamlConfiguration c);

}
```

Remember java enums are also normal classes. They can implement interfaces, have abstract methods and so on. You can't have it a non-`Enum` superclass and a non-private constructor though.

P.S.: For Java8, since this enum has one single abstract method, you can use a `Function` instead of making a lot of sub-classes, like this:

```
public enum ExportRules {
    A_RULE((c) -> {//...}),
    //...
    private final Function<YamlConfiguration, ExportRule> func;
    private ExportRules( Function<YamlConfiguration, ExportRule> fun) {
        func = fun;
    }

    public ExportRule fromFileConfiguration(YamlConfiguration c) {
        return func.apply(c);
    }

}
```

This is not classic polymorphism but it does the job and reduces scraps generated.

Comment: doesn't doing that requires each ExportRule to be entirely defined in the enum rather than it's own class? -- My ExportRule class has a bunch of logic both for construction from the configuration file and then the actual rule handling itself

Comment: No, setup is done inside a black box. The black box means clients don't know how the ExportRule is exactly assembled but what kind of ExportRule he will get in the end. You can do whatever you like here, including delegating the logic to the ExportRule classes.

Comment: so how would I actually delegate the construction to my fromConfigurationFile() method? wouldn't that still be a static constructor that Java won't let me target without explicitly knowing the class?

Comment: OH! Now I understand. Thank you! I'll edit my original post with the solution